# Select and Delete Word Heading to Next Page Break Macro VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with various headings. I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Find a Specific Heading from a "Heading 1" style.
2. Delete the heading, the content following the heading to and including the next page break.

So delete: heading + its content + page break

I know how to find text using a Word macro but I do not know how to search only the headings.

[image: Here is what needs to be deleted]

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I know how to find text using a Word macro but I do not know how to search only the headings` - same as searching for text, but with setting the `.Style` property of the `Find` object to the name of the style.

Comment: Your page break is manually placed? like series of dots with the word `Page Break`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you need to enable extend between selections.

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3") ' Search only "Heading 3"
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "MIPwDMU"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Extend
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^m"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Delete
```

This will delete all text between the Heading and the Page Break.